# How do I write Unit Tests for classes that inherit from Monobehaviour in Unity?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, unity-game-engine, nunit

I am trying to write unit tests in unity. I am currently following the example provided by Unity Test Runner:

exmple provided in Unity docs:
[image: exmple provided in Unity docs]

This is an example of the pattern I am using to carry out my actual test:

```
[UnityTest]
public IEnumerator ExampleTest()
{
    var test = new GameObject().AddComponent<MyScript>();

    test.testField = 100;

    yield return null;  

    Assert.AreEqual(100,test.testField);
}
```

When I try to run a similar test, with this EXACT pattern in Unity's test runner, it throws this error:

```
object reference not set to an instance of object
```

Is there any thing that I can do to resolve this?

Exception in Unity:

[image: Exception Output]

Comment: hmmm Ok? so where exactly is the error being thrown? what line?...could it be the `yield return null`?

Comment: Ah thanks! Forgot to add `yield return null`. I had that in my actual code.

Comment: The error is being thrown by the Unity Test Runner, I'll take a screenshot.

Comment: Updated the question to so the output of the exception.

Comment: How about just doing a `void` test? Based on what you are trying to test there is no need to return an iterator

Comment: In Unity, tests have to be `IEnumerators` or you will get this error, `Method returning void cannot have an expected result`.

Answer (score 1):

Based on what you are trying to test, there really is no need for the Iterator

```
[Test]
public void ExampleTest() {
    //Arrange
    var expected = 100;

    var test = new GameObject().AddComponent<MyScript>();

    test.testField = expected;

    //Act
    var actual = test.testField;

    //Assert
    Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
}
```

Reference [Writing and executing tests in Unity Test Runner](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PlaymodeTestFramework.html)

Comment: Yes, I tried it without the `UnityTest` attribute, no luck. Still gives me the same exception that I stated in my question :(.